# how to delete a salesforce commerce cloud cartridge?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud

I am trying to find documentation on this topic with no luck yet. I recently started a new position where I do a little of salesforce. My employer wants to terminate a contract with a third party (monetate), and they would like me to remove the monetate salesforce integration.

Does anybody knows how to delete a cartridge in Salesforce? or where I can find decent documentation?

Regards,
Natalia

Answer (score 0):

You can connect directly to the Cartridge Directory of your sandbox via WebDAV and delete the cartridge folder.

Check this out
https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/SiteDevelopment/CartridgeDirectoryviaWebDAV.html?resultof=%22%77%65%62%64%61%76%22%20